# How to Invoke the On-Board sound using C#/Command

Tags: c#, audio, kernel, directsound, motherboard

I need to invoke the sound from the motherboard/Onboard sound device, not from external speakers.
Like when Booting error sound.

I have been trying to invoke the sound which comes from the motherboard when it's booting failure or ram failure issue but all works I had been trying is goes for the external speakers

Comment: Please add more description and whatever you have tried in you'r question.

Comment: @arash I have been trying to invoke the sound which comes from the motherboard when it's booting failure or ram failure issue but all works I had been trying is goes for the external speakers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should just be as simple as:

```
Console.Beep();
```

Actually, seems it isn't that simple:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/

Comment: sorry @steve-j It doesn't work